# Linked lists - C

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I wanted to create a structure like the image below and for that I created two structures. One for all ordered vertices and another one with the adjacent vertices.

```
struct verticeslist{ //list with all ordered vertices
   int n;
   struct adjacentlist *pointer; //pointer to the list with adjacent vertices
   struct verticeslist *next;
};

struct adjacentlist{ //list with the adjacent vertices
   int n;
   struct adjacentlist *next;
};
```

[image: linked list]

Then with these structures I wanted to initialize them with the specific input from the user.

```
int main(){

    int i, vertices, links, start;
    struct verticeslist *lv;
    struct adjacentlist *lva;
    lv = (struct verticeslist *)malloc(sizeof(struct verticeslist));

    scanf("%d %d\n%d", &vertices, &links, &start); //save the values to create the list

    for (i=1; i<=vertices; i++){ //create and initialize the list
        lv->n = i;
        lv = lv->next;
    }

    while(lv != NULL){ //print the vertices list
        printf("%d ", lv->n);
        lv = lv->next;
    }

return 0;
}
```

I tried run this program and I get seg fault error. Why?

EDIT:
I changed my last code and understood what was wrong, but now I was trying to build the second part of the structure and I don't know how I can keep track of the first element because I assign the `lv->pointer = lva` in a loop. The `lv->pointer` at the end of the program will point to the last number of the another structure (adjacentlist).

```
scanf("%d ", &input);
while (input != EOF){
    lv = firstvert;
    while (lv != NULL){
        if(lv->n == input){
            scanf("%d\n", &adjacentnum);
            lva = (struct adjacentlist *)malloc(sizeof(struct adjacentlist));
            lva->n = adjacentnum;
            lva->next = NULL;
            lv->pointer = lva;
        }
        lv = lv->next; 
    }
    scanf("%d ", &input);
}
free(firstvert);
free(lv);
free(lva);

return 0;
```

Comment: You never initialize the `next` for your last element.

Comment: you should learn how to use a debugger, it would make you save a lot of time

Comment: http://www.go4expert.com/articles/reasons-segmentation-fault-c-t27220/ . And you haven't initialized next.

Comment: @Michał Szydłowski my last element has nothing, why do I need to initialize it?

Comment: @Miguel So what do you believe your uninitialized variable contains?

Comment: You set it to `NULL`

Comment: @Poldie It may have NULL but it can have junk too

Comment: @MichałSzydłowski Where?

Comment: @Miguel If you accept it can contain junk then why does your code assume it contains null?  As i've mentioned several times now, you need to set it to null yourself, otherwise your program will behave unpredictably).

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i=1; i<=vertices; i++){ //create and initialize the list
    lv->n = i;
    lv = lv->next;  // This has to be changed to create verticallist
}
```

Here, change

```
lv = lv->next;
```

To

```
lv->next = (struct verticeslist *)malloc(sizeof(struct verticeslist));
lv = lv->next
```

And don't forget to create a start for your vertical list, which will be used to traverse down the list when you are printing list values(within while loop).

Comment: You're making the same mistake he is; what is providing the null value of lv->next that's going to terminate the while loop?

Comment: Yes, lv->next will be null when it is initialised. But, within for loop, when he is creating the list, I hope it will work.

Comment: Where is he doing that?

Comment: @Poldie Can you be more specific?

Comment: Where is he setting lv->next to null?

Answer (score 1):

You have only allocated one node on your list, you need to allocate memory for each node that you use. something like this

```
for (i=1; i<=vertices; i++){ //create and initialize the list
    lv->n = i;
    lv->next = (struct verticeslist *)malloc(sizeof(struct verticeslist));
    lv = lv->next;
    lv->next = 0;
}
```

edited to add setting lv->next to null. Otherwise you will still get a seg fault when you try to read it later.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I think you should do, explanation for each step follow in the comments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct adjacentlist { //list with the adjacent vertices
   int n;
   struct adjacentlist *next;
};

struct verticeslist { //list with all ordered vertices
   int n;
   struct adjacentlist *pointer; //pointer to the list with adjacent vertices
   struct verticeslist *next;
};


int main(){

    int i, vertices, links, start;
    struct verticeslist *lv, *lfirstPtr;
    struct adjacentlist *lva;

    // Note that you aren't using links and start yet, what is the use of them?
    scanf("%d %d %d", &vertices, &links, &start);

    // Use print to debug when needed or give some feedback on what you did
    printf("\nvertices=%d links=%d start=%d", vertices, links, start);

    // Always initialize your fields when doing malloc, avoiding trash (non-value assigned)
    // being held on your variables. Later they can be used through some if to know if it is 
    // already initialized ()


    // Vertice List - Initialize the first element with 0 pos
    lv = (struct verticeslist*)malloc(sizeof( struct verticeslist));
    lv->pointer = NULL;
    lv->next = NULL;
    lv->n = 0;

    // Pointer to the first element (never change it, only if you want to remove your first element)
    lfirstPtr = lv;

    for (i=1; i <= vertices; i++){ //create and initialize the list
        // Updates the last element attaching a new allocated space
        lv->next = (struct verticeslist*)malloc(sizeof( struct verticeslist));
        // Makes lv point to this space
        lv = lv->next;

        // Fill it
        lv->pointer = NULL;
        lv->next = NULL;
        lv->n = i;
    }

    // Make it points to the first element and proceed to the loop
    // It's good to remember that the last element is pointed through its parent
    lv = lfirstPtr; 

    // note the NULL comparison
    while(lv != NULL){ //print the vertices list
        printf("\n%d ", lv->n);

        // Fill here when you have your adjacency list allocated (similar to what you've seen)
        // while (itAdj != NULL) {...} 

        // Go to the next Vertice position in the list
        lv = lv->next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Anyone that wants to check if the code works can place it here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php